# Which would be the logical way for shortcuts for up down left right arrows keys in a keyboard

Tags: web-app, keyboard, keyboard-layout

What would be the more intuitive way to wire [←] [→] [↑] [↓] keys to the left side of the keyboard for shortcuts?

Currently, my app is mirroring the behaviour with the key `e` (up) `d` (down) `s` (left) and `f` (right)

But I have a gut feeling that should be `w` (up), `s` (down), `a` (left) and `d` (right), which is the way for videos games.

I don't have any data to back up is purely gut instinct, anybody else has experience dealing with these shortcuts in specific? or what other apps are using?

Comment: I'm wondering why they would be bound to this weird layout in the first place.

Comment: Are your users gamers? Also, this article explains how WASD became a standard for games and why some people prefer ESDF: https://www.pcgamer.com/how-wasd-became-the-standard-pc-control-scheme/

Comment: no, they are not! thanks for sharing an article is a saas webapp

Answer (score 1):

As this binding is probably new to your users and will require some adaptation on their side, using the well known "w (up), s (down), a (left) and d (right)" will at least help those users who played games before. There would be no reason to use other bindings because it would also be confusing for people who played games in their life.  So it`s safe to stick to the nrom.